# Complex Analysis: Finding the image under a mapping using parametrisation

Tags: complex-analysis

For $f \subset (C - 0) \to C$

$$f(z) = 1/z$$

$z = x + iy: x + y = 1$

$(x,y) \in R^2$

find and sketch the image

So I tried simply subbing in $z = x + iy$ and $y = 1 - x$ to get

$$f(z) = \frac{x + (x - 1)i}{x^2 + y^2}$$

and
$$u(x, y) = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}$$

$$v(x, y) = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}-\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$$

Even by subbing $y = 1 - x$ into the denominator of $u(x, y)$ you can't solve a particular $x = g(u(x, y))$.
So how do I deal with the $$\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{1}{x^2 + (1-x)^2}$$

term in $v(x, y)$ to get an equation involving only $u$ and $v$ terms.

Answer (score 1):

if your constraint is $x+y=1$ then you can parametrized with
$x(t)=t, y(t)=1-t$
then
$u(t)=\frac{t}{t^2+(1-t^2)}, v(t)=\frac{t-1}{t^2+(1-t^2)}$

then plot the curve $t->(u(t), v(t))$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a subset of the circle $\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\left(y+\frac12\right)^2=\frac12$. In fact,$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):\left(\frac x{x^2+(x-1)^2}-\frac12\right)^2+\left(\frac{x-1}{x^2+(x-1)^2}+\frac12\right)^2=\frac12.$$Actually, the answer will be that circle minus one point (that point is the origin, of course).